# Can I put wallpaper on top of wallpaper on the ceiling?

Tags: wallpaper

After using heavily a steamer on the walls, the wallpaper of the ceiling is full of brownish areas due to steam. I also damaged the wallpaper in some corners.

I figured that instead of removing this ceiling wallpaper and paint the ceiling, it'll be easier to simply put a new wallpaper on top of this wallpaper.

But although I find a lot of resources about papering a bare ceiling, I found none about papering a ceiling on top of an existing ceiling wallpaper. Is it possible in the first place? Is there any problem compared to papering a bare ceiling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not paper over paper. In your case there is already a big chance that you have compromised the adhesion of the existing paper to the subsurface when the ceiling was exposed to the steam. Also to be considered is that the existing paper may not be a good surface to hold wall paper glue.

So I suggest getting the steamer back and removing the old ceiling paper too. Before putting on new paper make sure to seal the wall surface properly. The staining of the previous ceiling paper due to the steam could be an indicator that previous sealing was never done or has failed with age.